# Click on android permission in browser when using browserstack automate with selenium and appium

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, appium, browserstack

We are making an automated test suite with browserstack automate with our tests in selenium with appium.

For this test we need to play DRM protected content, while this works on all desktop platforms, we are having some trouble testing for android (and ios).
Since we need to tap on the allow button of the popup that appears when video tries to load.

[image: We want to click the allow option]

We've been attempting to click this button, but without much success.
We've tried fiddling around with the coordinates of the tap, but it does not seem to work/register.

We've noticed that either the context switch or the click cause the device to go to the home screen, since that is what we see in the recorded video. However the screenshots show the browser and the content without going to the homescreen (and the popup is gone too, but the video does not work)

This is the code we've been using to perform the tap action:

```
androidDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
int x = androidDriver.manage().window().getSize().width - 100;
int y = androidDriver.manage().window().getSize().height / 2 + 50;
new TouchAction<>(androidDriver).tap(PointOption.point(913, 1245)).perform();
androidDriver.context("CHROMIUM");
```

Input capabilities:

[image: Input capabilities]

Browser capabilities:

[image: Browser capabilities]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since we can't figure it out how to get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are switching to native context, you can find the allow button and click it. Based on the details and screenshot you shared, the following code snippet should do the trick:

```
//switch to native context
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

//find element with text attribute ALLOW and click it
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='ALLOW']")).click();

//switch back to chrome context
driver.context("CHROMIUM");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hey @Beele, Good that you found the solution. We are also in similar situation. We like to know is the DRM content playing in broswerstack ?? We have android application, DRM contant in broswerstack plays but only audio no video is playing. Can you let us know how is this with your application?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this capability for android as well. This automatically allow all android permissions.

```
cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@text='ALLOW'` is not working, try to find by the resource-id like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='android:id/button1']")).click();
```